# What is the rebel doing when the Millennium Falcon lands on the moon of Yavin?

Tags: star-wars, a-new-hope

See this image:

[image: Rebel aiming at the Falcon]

What is he doing there? Why is he aiming at the Millennium Falcon?

Comment: he's rebel paparazzi, trying to get the scope on the Falcon touching down for the Yavin daily.

Comment: @JustinC: Oh snap, why didn't I think of that. Wait until he publishes the Leia/Luke kiss from EpV!

Comment: Radar gun, Han is about to get a ticket in the mail

Comment: Pew, pew... got ya!

Comment: On the original theatrical release disc the rebel isn't aiming at anything at all; except for clouds the sky is empty above the jungle.  The _Falcon_ must have been added in one of the re-releases.

Comment: We used to joke that he was birdwatching.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

To avoid active scanning - from planet-bound scanners - that could be detected from Imperial space probes, the rebel is using a hand scanner to read the transponder code / weapons status / access code - you name it - of the Falcon.

What you don't see is that he calls then the base for confirmation.

Comment: Is that from canon, or a guess?

Comment: Well, at that point there is nothing they could do against the ship if it was an imperial aggressor, right?

Comment: @bitmask: The Falcoln was probably locked up in the sights of ground-based weaponry.  Had it been an aggressor it would have spread burning debris across the jungle and ruined some animal's days, but that's about it.

Comment: @Jeff: Good point!

Comment: *FYI*: That is just an educated guess, from a logical point of view (the rebel certainly wouldn't try to blast the Falcon to oblivion with a hand gun). Though I think I've read about that somewhere...

Comment: @Marc-André was that in A Gift from the Culture by Iain M Banks?

Comment: No, didn't read that one yet - still in the middle of the Yuuzhan Vong War :)

Comment: I bet Boba Fett was using a similar device to discretely scan the Falcon & find its heading in The Empire Strikes Back (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_cDA9JiRerM).

Answer (score 16):

This individual is identified on the [Starwars.com databank website](http://www.starwars.com/news/yavin-4-rebels-guardians-of-the-hidden-fortress) as Corporal Osleo Prennert. Apparently he was acting as a sentry for the base. The device in his hand appears to be some kind of scanner rather than a gun.

> Corporal Osleo Prennert was the sentry on duty when the Millennium
>   Falcon landed on Yavin 4.

[image]

And from the film's [junior novelisation](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Episode_IV:_A_New_Hope_(junior_novelization))

> ...a Rebel sentry visually monitored the freighter’s atmospheric descent
>   from an observation tower, which was little more than a barrel-topped
>   pole that extended high above the jungle floor